# How to combine two sums functions into one code which would give an output as the table in the following style?

Tags: r, sum

I have written the following two codes in R.The first one returns the value 41 and the second one returns 9.

```
sum(dflapop2$missingsalary==1 & is.na(dflapop2$age))
sum(dflapop2$missingsalary==1 & is.na(dflapop2$edlevel))
```

I want both codes combined in one, which would return the following table:

```
age  edlevel
 41        9
```

Any idea how I could do this?

Comment: Read my question. I want age and edlevel to appear on top of each output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like below?

```
colSums(is.na(subset(dflapop2,missingsalary==1)[c("age","edlevel")]))
```

or

```
sapply(is.na(subset(dflapop2,missingsalary==1)[c("age","edlevel")]),sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dflapop2 %>%
      filter(missingsalary == 1) %>%
      summarise(across(c(age, edlevel), ~ sum(is.na(.))))
```